# How do I get an instance of a class that extends a JPanel to display in another classes JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

incomePanel displays inside of IncomeAndSpendingPanel, but if I move all the incomePanel code into it's own class (like I have with SpendingPanel and TransactionAdder) and try to add them to IncomeAndSpendingPanel that way nothing displays. I'm just trying to clean up my code and separate it into different parts.

```
public class IncomeAndSpendingPanel extends JPanel {

    private ColorX cx = new ColorX();
    DefaultTableModel incomeTableModel;
    DefaultTableModel spendingTableModel;


    private String[] incomeColumnHeadings = {"Date","Description","Amount"};
    private String[] spendingColumnHeadings = {"Date","Description","Amount","Category"};

    Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    CompoundBorder line = new CompoundBorder(empty, blackLine);

    public IncomeAndSpendingPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new TransactionAdder(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new SpendingPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);


        JPanel incomePanel;
        Border incomePanelBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(line, "INCOME");
        JTable incomeTransactionInputTable;


        incomePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

        incomePanel.setBorder(incomePanelBorder);

        incomeTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(50, incomeColumnHeadings.length);
        incomeTableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(incomeColumnHeadings);

        incomeTransactionInputTable = new JTable(incomeTableModel);
        incomeTransactionInputTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(1);
        incomeTransactionInputTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        incomeTransactionInputTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(10);

        incomePanel.add(new JScrollPane(incomeTransactionInputTable));

        add(incomePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

This is the class I built for TransactionAdder, and nothing displays when I try to add it to the IncomeAndSpendingPanel, I've tried creating a TransactionAdder transactionAdder = new TransactionAdder(); and then adding the instance of TransactionAdder like this

```
add(transactionAdder, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

But nothing displays on the IncomeAndSpendingPanel that way either

```
public class TransactionAdder extends JPanel {

    DefaultTableModel model3;
    DefaultTableModel model4;

    private String[] incomeColumnHeadings = {"Date","Description","Amount"};
    private String[] spendingColumnHeadings = {"Date","Description","Amount","Category"};

    Border empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    Border blackLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    CompoundBorder line = new CompoundBorder(empty, blackLine);

    JTable incomeTransactionTable;
    JTable spendingTransactionTable;
    JPanel transactionAdderPanel;
    Border transactionAdderPanelBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(line, "ADD TRANSACTION");
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    JScrollPane jScrollPane1;

    public TransactionAdder() {

        transactionAdderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

        transactionAdderPanel.setBorder(transactionAdderPanelBorder);

        model3 = new DefaultTableModel(1, incomeColumnHeadings.length);
        model3.setColumnIdentifiers(incomeColumnHeadings);
        model4 = new DefaultTableModel(1, spendingColumnHeadings.length);
        model4.setColumnIdentifiers(spendingColumnHeadings);

        transactionAdderPanel.add(new JButton("Add New Income"));

        incomeTransactionTable = new JTable(model3);
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(incomeTransactionTable);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 38));
        transactionAdderPanel.add(jScrollPane);

        transactionAdderPanel.add(new JButton("Add New Spending"));

        spendingTransactionTable = new JTable(model4);
        jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(spendingTransactionTable);
        jScrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 38));
        transactionAdderPanel.add(jScrollPane1);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots to say here...firstly you probably need to be using a JFrame so please read about top level containers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Also since you are using inheritance you definitely need to move all those base class method calls to a method and only use the constructor to initialize instance variables. If you don't you could have all kinds of problems for when any JPanel object is created because you have override-able method calls during initialization.

However, when you add `incomePanel` and `TransactionAdder`

1. You never set either of these `.setVisible(true)`
2. You never set your `IncomeAndSpendingPanel` as `.setVisible(true)`
3. You never set `IncomeAndSpendingPanel` to any size (use the `Dimension` class)
4. You never used the container [hierarchy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Please go make those contained within a JFrame and change your code to look something more like this:

```
class IncomeAndSpendingPanel extends JFrame
{
   //Instance variables

   public IncomeAndSpendingPanel()
   {
     //initialize instance variables
     createAndShowGui();
   }

   private void createAndShowGui()
   {
     //Your code
     this.setVisible(true);
   }
```

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to stack-overflow and I think my question may have had too little context. This is a snip of class code out of a larger budget program I am working on. I do have a JFrame in another class that these panels are added to. I guess what it came down to was that I needed to add the actual panel (transactionAdderPanel) instead of trying to add a new instance of the class. It displays now. Thanks for the suggestions!